# Return multiple items from spring batch ItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have data from `table A` like this:

```
ID   Name   Subject
1    AAA    music;history;math
2    BBB    music
3    CCC    math;history
```

and I have used `ItemReader` to get the list from this table:

```
public StoredProcedureItemReader<Student> getList() {
    StoredProcedureItemReader<Student> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<Student>();
    SqlParameter[] parameters = { 
            new SqlInOutParameter("v_cursor", Types.REF_CURSOR)
            };      
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setProcedureName("package.GET_STUDENTLIST");
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Student.class));
    reader.setParameters(parameters);
    reader.setRefCursorPosition(1);   

    return reader;
}
```

Because of some reasons, I can't change the Stored Procedure and it will return all items in column Subject (that means the list will have 3 objects). How could I modify the `StoredProcedureItemReader` to return a separative item of the Subject column? 

My expect is that the list should have 6 objects:

```
ID   Name   Subject
1    AAA    music
1    AAA    history
1    AAA    math
2    BBB    music
3    CCC    math
3    CCC    history
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement your custom `RowMapper` like below:

```
 StoredProcedureItemReader<List<Student>> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<List<Student>>();
SqlParameter[] parameters = { 
            new SqlInOutParameter("v_cursor", Types.REF_CURSOR)
            };      
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setProcedureName("package.GET_STUDENTLIST");
    reader.setRowMapper(new RowMapper<List<Student>>(){  
        @Override  
        public List<Student> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException { 
            String[] sub = rs.getString(3).split(";");
            List<Student> temp = new ArrayList<Student>();
            for(int i =0 ; i < sub.length ; i ++){
             Student s =new Student();  
             s.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
             s.setName(rs.getString(2)); 
             s.setSubject(sub[i]);
             temp.add(s);
            }

            return temp;  
        }  
        });  
    reader.setParameters(parameters);
    reader.setRefCursorPosition(1);   

    return reader;
```

Please note I have also updated `ItemReader` class to expect `List<Student>` instead of `Student` class and yes you can do changes accordingly to avoid run time exceptions like `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Can we do this for itemWriter()?

Comment: What exactly you want to do for itemWriter()?

Comment: processor return 3 object students s with s.getSubject will return  "music;history;math" and "music" and "math;history". In itemWriter, can I split Subject by ";" and use loop to write into database?

Comment: Yes, definitely you can do that.

Comment: I have tried but I can't take each object in itemWriter. Seem like it returns a list. However, your solution above has solved my problems.